# MIDL Compiler error: MIDL

Tags: com, midl, opc

When I use MIDL to compile a IDL file to .h and .c, I get a error said:

**midl : command line error MIDL1004 : cannot execute C preprocessor cl.exe.**

Please kindly help me, I do not know why.

The MIDL compiler which I use is part of VC++ 6.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your environment is not correctly set. Try calling `vcvars32` before compiling.